# Is applying a LIMIT to a Count() query an optimization?

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate

Salesforce has [recently updated](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_soql_count_limits.htm) the way that the Apex Governor counts `Count()` query row limits so that the entire aggregate is a single SOQL Row (as opposed to previously where each aggregated row was treated as a SOQL row).

The old way to deal with this was to add a `LIMIT` clause to your count query. Something like:

```
SELECT Count() FROM Lead WHERE IsConverted = TRUE LIMIT 5000
```

However, now that the `Count()` is no longer at risk of hitting the SOQL Rows limit, is there still a benefit to applying a LIMIT to a `Count()` query? Specifically, I'm wondering this from a performance perspective.

For a specific example, let's say I have an org that has hundreds of thousands of records in one of the objects. I need to write a query that tests if, say, there are more than 10,000 rows matching a certain criteria. In the current platform version, are there any differences between

```
SELECT Count() FROM My_Object__c WHERE Category__c = :someCategory LIMIT 10001
```

and

```
SELECT Count() FROM My_Object__c WHERE Category__c = :someCategory
```

(Assuming `Category__c` is an external id field so it's indexed)

Comment: Check the query plan in your org. It can very based on the objects, indexes, and total number of records.

Comment: @battery.cord good advice - I was hoping that maybe there was a blanket best-practice. It's a little hard to optimize each query as this is for an ISV application (where each client has different data requirements). Without something like, though, running query plan on each query seems the best way to go.